# JSON POST Import

Tags: javascript, json, post

I am trying to import data from a JSON POST API into a Google Sheet.  I have been able to log the full JSON response but now can't filter it to just the attribute that I require as I keep getting an error saying that the attribute is 'undefined' when I try to log DIV1.  I have tried testing it for other parameters such as the DrawDate and DrawType, but keep getting the same message.

```
function main() {

// Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
var data = {
  'CompanyId': 'GoldenCasket',
  'MaxDrawCount': 1,
  'OptionalProductFilter':['OzLotto']};

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://data.api.thelott.com/sales/vmax/web/data/lotto/opendraws', options);

  Logger.log('output: '+ response);          

  var json = JSON.parse(response)
  var DIV1 = json["Div1Amount"];

  Logger.log(DIV1) 
}
```

I am getting this response to the request, but I would like to receive just the Div1Amount.

```
output: 
{
   "Draws":[
      {
         "ProductId":"OzLotto",
         "DrawNumber":1323,
         "DrawDisplayName":"Oz Lotto $80,000,000",
         "DrawDate":"2019-06-25T00:00:00",
         "DrawLogoUrl":"http://media.tatts.com/TattsServices/Lotto/Products/OzLotto_v1.png",
         "DrawType":"Jackpot",
         "Div1Amount":80000000.0000,
         "IsDiv1Estimated":false,
         "IsDiv1Unknown":false,
         "DrawCloseDateTimeUTC":"2019-06-25T09:35:00",
         "DrawEndSellDateTimeUTC":"2019-06-25T09:30:00",
         "DrawCountDownTimerSeconds":538150.0
      }
   ],
   "ErrorInfo":null,
   "Success":true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your response, `Div1Amount` is inisde `Draws` list. So, to do that, you have to get the list and iterate through the list then `var DIV1 = listObj["Div1Amount"];` will work. Sample code:

```
//after `var json = JSON.parse(response)` line, change your code with this:

var drawList=json ["Draws"];
//now iterate the list:
for(var i=0;i<drawList.length;i++)
{
  var DIV1=drawList[i]["Div1Amount"];
  console.log(DIV1);
}
```